# Failed to enable unit: Unit file named.service does not exist

Tags: dns, bind

everyone
After installing bind9

```
apt install -y bind9 bind9utils bind9-doc dnsutils
```

I want to enable named service.

```
systemctl enable named
```

But I get this error:

```
Failed to enable unit: Unit file named.service does not exist.
```

Does anyone has any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

try this command

```
systemctl enable bind9
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1173811)